# MySQLi wrapper for prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been using a wrapper class for my database functions for a long time now.  A few years back I upgraded it to use `mysqli_` instead of the depreciated `mysql_` functions which made the website transgress perfectly during PHP version upgrades.

With a more recent upgrade to my wrapper I wrote a class to do prepared statemtnts from an mulit-array to help keep things a little neater.

This is the way I've done it.

**index.php** - Testing File

```
/* Set Parameters
    i - integer
    d - double
    s - string
    b - BLOB
 */
 $params = array(
    array('s' => $_GET["id"]),
    array('i' => $_GET["two"])
 );

 $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `".$db->prefix."articles` SET `categoryID`= ? , `articleID`= ? ");
 $select2 = $db->execute($params);
 $db->close();
```

You can also reset the `$params` array with a different data set and `$db->execute($params)` again to insert another row.

**database.class.php**

```
function prepare($sql) {
    $this->last_query = $sql; //Save query to show later on.
    $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
}

function close() {
    $this->stmt->close();
}

function execute($params) {
    $ident = '';
    $parameters = '';
    $vars = array();
    if($this->stmt) {
        foreach($params as $k => $v) {
            foreach($v as $a => $b) {
                $ident  .= $a;
                $vars[] .= $b;
                $parameters .= $a.' => '.$b.'<br>'; // For MySQL error reporting
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bind_param( $ident , ...$vars );
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
        $this->stmt->execute();
        $result = $this->stmt->get_result();
        return $result;
    }
    else {
        if($this->conn->error) {
            $this->last_error = $this->conn->error;
            $sql = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $sql));
            $this->log_error("MySQL",$this->last_error." ☼ ".$sql);
        }
    }
    //$data = $result->fetch_all();
}
```

My questions are:

1. Will the way I have it slow it down any?
2. Can anyone come up with a better solution and keep it neat?  I like the neatness of having the info  lined up in the array; not saying it's the best solution but it does work.  I haven't found a nice solution to keep things totally organized.
3. Do you see any downfalls to this route?

The website I work on will all be running PHP 7.0 (or at least PHP 5.7 until I can upgrade them to the newer version).

Comment: Slow it down ... from what? Compared to what?

Comment: "Neat", "better", "nice", "totally organized" all emotional, subjective terms without clear requirements

Comment: What category of "downfalls"? Are you asking for code review / bug hunting? Sorry, this question isn't answerable in its current form.

Comment: I think this should be moved to code review.

Comment: Putting mysqli in a wrapper is a great idea. As you eventually refactor, it will get better.

Comment: It looks good, but I would get rid of all this error reporting. Enable MySQLi exceptions and it should be enough for you.

Comment: This question will likely be closed here, but I'll gladly answer if you post it on the coderevew@stackexchange. Though I already have one. This function can be made much simpler: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 8.2 it is now possible out-of-box using a single statement.

Use **mysqli::execute_query** for this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Col1=? and Col2=?';
$result = $mysqli->execute_query($query, ['Col1Value', 'Col1Value']);

foreach ($result as $row) {
   ...
}
```

More info here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.execute-query